Movie about vampires with a young doctor falling in love with a blond vampire
I don't remember much about this, it was between 80s and 90s maybe. It was about a young doctor that meets a blond vampire girl and falls in love with her, i think she was part of a coven or something and they don't want them to be together. I remember a scene where they are rowing a boat in a lake and another where the girl is hungry and the doctor takes blood from the blood bank in the hospital to feed her.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

Was it the TV movie Nightlife (1989)? I remember the boat scene and the American doctor and a European vampire girl, but the main character was an evil vampire named Vlad.
